# Getting ORA-01858 in Program but working in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-01858

We have a program that ERRORS out with ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

```
DECLARE
  
    l_prev_purchase_batch_id    xx_rep_status.reporting_status_id%type;
    l_tax_calendar_period       xx_rep_status.tax_calendar_period%type := 'JAN-06';
    
BEGIN
  
    SELECT  status.reporting_status_id          
      INTO  l_prev_purchase_batch_id
      FROM  xx_rep_status status
     WHERE  status.vat_reporting_entity_id = 300100097478219
       AND  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(status.tax_calendar_period, 'MM/YY'), 'MM/YY') = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(l_tax_calendar_period, 'MM/YY'), -1), 'MM/YY')
       AND  status.source NOT IN ('GL', 'AR', 'AP')
       AND  status.source = 'P2P';
       
END;
```

But when we run it directly from SQL Developer on the same database, it works fine.
I checked the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` from the database session and the Program session, and they match:

```
select  VALUE, 'SESSION_NLS_DATE_FORMAT' parameter
from    nls_session_parameters
where   parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
UNION ALL
select  VALUE, 'DB_NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
from    nls_database_parameters
where   parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
UNION ALL
select  VALUE, 'SESSION_NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE'
from    nls_session_parameters
where   parameter = 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE'
UNION ALL
select  VALUE, 'DB_NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE'
from    nls_database_parameters
where   parameter = 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE';
```

**SQL Developer**

```
VALUE         PARAMETER                
------------- -------------------------
DD-MON-RR     SESSION_NLS_DATE_FORMAT  
DD-MON-RR     DB_NLS_DATE_FORMAT       
AMERICAN      SESSION_NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE
AMERICAN      DB_NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE
```

**Application**

```
VALUE                       PARAMETER                
--------------------------- -------------------------
YYYY-MM-DD                  SESSION_NLS_DATE_FORMAT  
DD-MON-RR                   DB_NLS_DATE_FORMAT       
NUMERIC DATE LANGUAGE       SESSION_NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE
AMERICAN                    DB_NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE
```

I have tried passing the value of `l_tax_calendar_period` to another variable but it's still having issues.
The value of `l_tax_calendar_period` changes such as '01-01' OR 'JAN-01', depending on the setup.

I have been stuck on this for quite some time, any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Mixing month abbreviations and numbers in the same data seems... odd, and relying on Oracle's lax date conversion isn't ideal. But storing them as strings also isn't ideal as you could have data that isn't either. Under what settings/setup does the application error - always, or only with month abbreviations, or for a specific month? And is the application's DB session in the same language as SQL Developer? (Check `nls_date_language` from both sessions.) If the month abbreviation being passed in doesn't match that language then you'll get that error. Maybe override that in the `to_date` call?

Comment: It's not the database language, it's the *session* language. Your application may have different NLS settings to SQL Developer, which take precedence over whatever is in `nls_database_parameters`.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I was supposed to comment but it was too long. i edited the post with details of the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`, can you take a look?

Comment: Well, it is obvious that the code should fail, because the string 'JAN-06' does not match the format 'MM/YY'. So, rather than wondering how this code misteriously runs in one application, just correct the code, I'd say. On a side note: Why do you expect the period column to contain a string that matches 'MM/YY', then convert it to a date and then back to the original string? That doesn't seem to make any sense. And why do you store years with two digits only? This, too, is generally a bad idea.

Comment: It's not really mysterious, Oracle is just lax by default. And if there is a requirement to handle numeric and string months - however much that makes me shudder - then it has to be handled somehow; though choosing the right format mask based on the data might be preferable.

Comment: @MigsIsip - my answer already covers that, but I've now included your actual NLS setting as an example too.

Answer (score 3):

You don't appear to be doing any implicit conversion or relying on the session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting. But when you use month abbreviations you are relying on `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`.

If you have value like `JAN-01` then Oracle's 'helpful' default behaviour of loose interpretation of the format models means that it will be converted correctly to 2006-01-01, but only if the session recognised the `JAN` as a valid month abbreviation (or name) in its language.

```
select to_date('Jan-06', 'MM/YY') from dual
```

| TO_DATE('JAN-06','MM/YY') |
| --- |
| 01-JAN-06 |

With a session in a different language that might not work, and can give the error you are seeing:

```
alter session set nls_date_language = French

select to_date('Jan-06', 'MM/YY') from dual

ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

or with the 'numeric' date language your application is actually using:

```
alter session set nls_date_language = 'numeric date language'

select to_date('Jan-06', 'MM/YY') from dual

ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Assuming all the data in your table is in a single language - which may not be the case if it's as free-form as it looks - then you can override the session setting in the `to_date()` call:

```
select to_date('Jan-06', 'MM/YY', 'nls_date_language=English') from dual
```

| TO_DATE('JAN-06','MM/YY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') |
| --- |
| 01-01-06 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vsr3DCGU)

If the values might be in multiple languages then your program would have to identify them and pass the correct language into your DB code; or convert to a date itself.

It would probably still be preferable to only use month numbers, and constrain the column to only allow valid values; or only use English names, also constrained; or store a nominal date instead of any MM/YY pattern. I suspect that's out of your control though...